# How to add multiple values in dictionary for a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a python code where i want to take multiple or 3 number inputs from user for one key in dictionary . Can anyone please help .  Appreciate in advance

I think output will be as given below .
For key "ABC" assigned/values are 67,68,69.

{ABC : [67, 68, 69]}

````
m=0
empty_dic = {}
numbers = []
name = input()
key = name
while m < 3:
    n = int(input())
    numbers.append(n)
    m += 1
empty_dic.setdefault(key, numbers)
empty_dic[key].append(numbers)
print(empty_dic)```
````

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "I think output will be ..." is inappropriate: if you don't know what your program does, you do not have a Stack Overflow post.  Testing and initial diagnosis are your task, not ours.

Comment: What's your question? In addition to Prune's links, you should read the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) -- it gives you a nice checklist to ensure your question is a good, answerable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here if you want to add multiple numbers

```
a_list = []
a_dict = {'Number': a_list}

#here so the will loop will be runing
RUN = True

while RUN:
    a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    l = a_list.append(a)
    quit_the_while = input('Enter q to quit or any thing to add more number: ')
    if 'q' in quit_the_while:
        break
    else:
        continue

print(a_dict)
```

here for 3 numbers only

```
a_list = []
a_dict = {'Number': a_list}

while len(a_list) < 3:
    a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    l = a_list.append(a)

print(a_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```py
m=0
empty_dic = {}
numbers = []
name = input()
key = name
while m < 3:
    n = int(input())
    numbers.append(n)
    m += 1
empty_dic[key]= numbers
print(empty_dic)
```